# Web server using python on raspberry pi, unreachable from LAN or Internet

Tags: python, networking, raspberry-pi, webserver

So, I have to write a simple web server running on a Raspberry Pi, using socket and python, printing “Got a request!” to the screen of the RPi when server receives a request.

To try this, I will type the IP address of the RPi (192.168.8.4) into the address line of the browser, from
a) A laptop in the same LAN (192.168.8.33)
b) a laptop in a different LAN, for example a mobile phone using 4G

Here is my code:

```
import socket
import sys

# --- 1 Create socket ---
my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
my_socket_info = socket.getaddrinfo(None, 80)  #Listening for any address
HOST, PORT = my_socket_info[3][4]
print(HOST, PORT)  #IP and port
#print(my_socket_info)

# --- 2 Bind socket ---
try:
    my_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error:
    print("Failed to bind")
    sys.exit()

# --- 3 Listen for a connection ---
my_socket.listen(5)

# --- 4 Accept connection ---
while True:
    client_connection, client_address = my_socket.accept()
    # --- 5 Receive data ---
    data = client_connection.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    print ("Got a request!")
    print (data)

    # --- 6 Send response ---
    http_response = b"\HTTP/1.1 200 OK "
    client_connection.sendall(http_response)

client_connection.close()
my_socket.close()
```

So, I have successfully tested my server by running netcat on the raspberry, acting as Client as well, see picture below:

[image: Testing web server using netcat]

BUT, when I try to reach the web server from my laptop (192.168.8.33) or from the Internet, I just can´t.

[image]

**So, I´m stuck here, what else do I have to do?
-to connect from same network
-to connect from the Internet**

*I have enabled "virtual server" in my Huawei home router to forward port 80 to my RPi IP, as follows:
Port WAN: 80
IP LAN: 192.168.8.4 (RPi address)
Port LAN: 80
Protocol: TCP
State: Active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is printed out. It says `127.0.0.1 80` which is the only accesible place. Instead of `my_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))` do `my_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", "80"))`. That should fix it.

Comment: Worked perfectly a) from raspberry b) from LAN c) from Internet